# Real Time App with Python - Tornado - Falcon - Django

Tags: python, django, tornado, falcon

i have to develop a Real Time Application that supports thousands of users with Python. The question: decide which framework and architecture use.

The first option is:

- Falcon only (Admin and API)

The second:

- Tornado manage request, Admin runs Django and API runs Falcon

Another problem is database. Could be one only RethinkDB (1st option), or two, with Postgresql (2nd option).

Which of these option is the best? Should try something different?

PD: One fancy implementation could be with Tornado sockets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your question needs to be more specific.

Without more detail about the application my general suggestion would be to not complicate things by using many frameworks, just pick one that does everything you need.

Unless you are planning to design an asynchronous API forget about Tornado. If your application is very small and has a simple API then you could consider Falcon because of it's short learning curve. Otherwise I'd suggest going with Django.

As for the DB, it's nearly impossible to provide a suggestion without understanding what type of data you are planning to store? What is your expected read/write ratio? Do you already have operational experience with any DBs?

Comment: Yes, i think will use only Falcon for everthing and see whats happen.